# I have an issue in accessing the html elements in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have linked my html elements with ID to can read it

I can access the asp elements inside the same page in this tag

```
<script></script>
```

but I can't access its in the separate code file called"Default.aspx.cs"

also the ordinary html elements can't access its inside `<script></script>`
rather than the separate code file "Default.aspx.cs"

```
<%@ language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>A few goals</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script runat="server">

    </script>
</head>
<body runat="server" onload="checkConnection">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top:200px;">
                <center>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h3>Authentication Step</h3>
                        <hr />
                        <form runat="server">
                            <input type="text" id="untxt" runat="server" placeholder="Username"/>
                            <input type="password" id="pwdtxt" runat="server" placeholder="Password"/>
                            <input type="submit" id="enterbtn" runat="server" value="Enter" />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <center><asp:Label ID="errmsg" runat="server">

                            </asp:Label></center>
                            <br />
                            <center><b style="color:darkred;">if account not exist , it will create a new account automaticity</b></center>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need easy way to access these elements easily , thanks

Comment: I can't understand your question and I am sure nobody else can either. Try to clarify.

Comment: I am also can't understand this question please clarify

Comment: @Crowcoder
this element for example <asp:Label ID="errmsg" runat="server">                            </asp:Label>
-- errmsg.Text is not readable inside "Default.aspx.cs" page

Comment: @Marzouk 
I hope to get it

Comment: where is your @Page directive for the page ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just access html tags in your .cs file, even if you add IDs to them, this is only for javascript and css. You can access the elements marked with `<asp:.../>` or `<asp:...></asp>` and should contain runat=server.

```
<asp:Button id="id" text="label" OnClick="sub" runat="server" />
```

This button you should be able to access throgh ID id in your Default.cs. I suggest you to take a look at [this documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_forms.asp).

Comment: Hello , the same problem - 
with your own code - "<asp:Button id="id" text="label" OnClick="sub" runat="server" />
"
in Default.aspx.cs -- id.Text "id does not exist in the current context

Comment: Have you added that line of code to Default, and tried to access it from Default.cs?  Also have you saved Default after the modification? If yes where have you added it?

Comment: Oh , I got it
I forgot to add this in the first line CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"
my bad!!

Comment: Good, it's great you found it out! Why do you constructed it manually, I guess asp,net generates a working sample automatically

Comment: as a beginner , I should try to write all codes from scratch
-- to understand how ASP work